# How to make this OTPView ? I want to give input through layout button not with Softkeyboard in Xamain.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

[image]

I want to make this ui the button on the layout when i press the button the value will be enter into the pincode place how to desin this ui in xamarin.android ?Any helping Resource for this.

Comment: Check out this [library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5596)

Comment: In this library i dont like the keyboard background? Please can you tell me how i can customize the background

Comment: @rahat if you have any idea about it

Comment: well then, please make your own, ten buttons and one textview, one custom edit text and one label

Comment: So I can Make with Fragment Create pin and confirm pin?

Comment: @rahat ??????.fd

Comment: Yes, you can do that,